# OpenGL Issue with Camera(?)

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm learning OpenGL and I have a problem with my program where I'm supposed to make the solar system.

First of all here's the code I use to setup my ModelView Matrix:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(20, 1, 0, 0);
glTranslatef(0, -20, -60);
```

And then I draw the orbits using line loops and the sun is a gluSphere:

```
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(1, 0.4f, 0);
glTranslatef(0, -2, 0);
gluSphere(gluNewQuadric(), 4, 30, 30);
glPopMatrix();
```

And here's the result:

[image: SolarSystem1]

But then, when I "zoom in" using this code:

```
if (key=='w')
{
    glTranslatef(0, 1, 2.4);
}
else if (key=='s')
{
    glTranslatef(0, -1, -2.4);
}
```

this happens:

[image]

the lines stay in front of the sphere. I know it's probably something dumb I'm doing but I'm just starting to learn and this is really slowing me down..
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't have the depth test turned on.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

You may also need to fiddle with the depth test parameters, though usually the default setting is sufficient.

```
glDepthfunc(GL_LESS);
```

I'd also like to take this time to strongly recommend that you stop using OpenGL's Immediate Mode and OpenGL's Fixed Function Pipeline, and [learn Modern OpenGL](http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Introduction).

Comment: That was so easy! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mykod Make sure to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: I will, I can only do it in one minute! About OpenGL's Immediate Mode, I'm reading more about it but I'm in college having OpenGL classes and that is the way I have been told to do. Is it that bad? :/

Comment: @Mykod Well, it's functional. But it won't be useful outside of college, where performance constraints will obviate the use of Immediate Mode, and Design constraints will obviate the use of the Fixed Function Pipeline. You may want to ask your professor if they have any plans to teach modern OpenGL, or if there are any classes available which focus on bridging students from OpenGL 1.x to OpenGL 3.x.